# Python os.stat not expanding wildcard in filename

Tags: python

Probably something really stupid I am doing but can someone please assist.  All I am trying to do is stat a file.  Python will not make this happen, when I debug my python variables I can stat in the shell with it's output. Please see below:

```
[root@logmaster output]# cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logrip_log_not_stale.py

import os
import sys
import datetime
import time

# Nagios return values
nagiosRetValOk       = 0
nagiosRetValWarn     = 1
nagiosRetValCritical = 2

# Below is the filename I am after
#logrip-out-2016-03-19-1458386101

dateFormat = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
logFormat = "/home/famnet/logs/output/logrip-out-%s-*" % dateFormat


print os.stat(logFormat)
```

Here is what happens when I run the basic script:

```
    [root@logmaster output]# python /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logrip_log_not_stale.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logrip_log_not_stale.py", line 36, in <module>
        print os.stat(logFormat)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/famnet/logs/output/logrip-out-2016-03-19-*'
```

Please forgive me if this is an easy waste of time for some experts.

Thanks,
However when I take the output of my print debug and run in the shell it works.

```
[root@logmaster output]# stat /home/famnet/logs/output/logrip-out-2016-03-19-*
  File: `/home/famnet/logs/output/logrip-out-2016-03-19-1458386101'
  Size: 42374797        Blocks: 82776      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 36590817    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  504/  famnet)   Gid: ( 1100/   staff)
Access: 2016-03-19 07:15:01.725794193 -0400
Modify: 2016-03-19 07:44:09.847793116 -0400
Change: 2016-03-19 07:44:09.847793116 -0400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expansion of wildcards is a feature of many common shells, such as `bash` in this case. It is not a feature of the system call underlying `os.stat`.

If you want to call `os.stat` against more than one file, you'll have to list them (using something like `glob.glob`) first, then call `os.stat` once per path. Something like this:

```
for full_path in glob.glob(logFormat):
    print os.stat(full_path)
```

Observe as well that a path with a wildcard may expand to multiple concrete paths, which can work with the command-line `STAT(1)`, but will certainly break `os.stat` which takes only a single path argument.

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you very much.  I have accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

`os.stat` won't auto-expand the wildcard...  try using `glob`